# Flex - Actionscript - RegExp - Retrieve Specific Data From a String

Tags: regex, apache-flex, actionscript

I have been messing with this for a while now, and decided to post on here to see if anyone could help out. I even messed around with the RegExr tool (with no luck):
http://gskinner.com/RegExr

Anyway, I have a String that contains the verbiage (without the quotes):
"13.5 to 14.1"

I need to create a var with the first number: 13.5 and a var with the second number: 14.1

So I want the following result:

var firstVal:String = 13.5;
var secondVal:String = 14.1;

I got it to work by doing the following for the first number: 
var lowRegExp:RegExp=/\d[0-9].\d[0-9]/;

And for the second number I did this:
var highRegExp:RegExp=/\d[0-9].\d[0-9]$/;

My problem here is that I will not know the format of the String. It could also look like this (two digits trailing the decimal):
13.57 to 14.10

So I need to make sure that it works using the following combinations:
13.50 to 14.1, 13.5 to 14.10, 3.50 to 4.10, 3.5 to 4.1 (all combinations must work)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I got to work. I am not sure how clean this is, and I am not a fan of hard coding, but it works for all scenarios. If someone knows a clean way to do this, please let me know.

```
var myString:String="13.5 to 14.1";
var firstVal:String=myString.substring(0, myString.search(" to "));
var secondVal:String=myString.substring((myString.search(" to ") + 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty straight forward, you want the following:
 - Any # of digits, followed by a period literal, followed by any # of digits.

```
Pattern: \d+\.\d+
So use something similar:
var mystr:String = "15.4 to 153.93";
var tokens:Array = mystr.match(/\d+\.\d+/g);
```

Also, I have gotten myself in the habit of using [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com) which is way faster than iterative testing in your application. ;)